# Why don't my original column headers show up as data types (dtypes) in Python pandas after creating a pivot table?

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation, pivot-table

I've been unable to find info on this; maybe I'm asking the wrong question, but:

I've created two pivot tables from data:

```
In [1]:  Test1 = pd.pivot_table(data,index=['Date','Time','Basket'],
         values=['Total'],aggfunc=np.sum)
```

and

```
In [2]:  Test2 = pd.pivot_table(data,index=['Date','Time','Basket'],
         values=['Total'],aggfunc=len)
```

To calculate the total amount per basket and the number of items per basket respectively.  I get an output as a DataFrame for each, however, the output creates 'Total' as a column heading above the other original column headings(in the case below for the amount per basket) and also has empty cells.

```
                                 Total
Date         Time       Basket  
07/29/05    10:00:04    103885   35.95
            10:00:12    100984   28.97
```

When I concatenate these new DataFrames for amount per basket and number of items per basket, I get this table:

```
                                Total   Total
Date        Time        Basket      
07/29/05    10:00:04    103885    9     35.95
            10:00:12    100984    8     28.97
```

And when I check data types, I get an output that says only Total and Total are datatypes.

```
Total    float64
Total    float64
dtype: object
```

My questions is twofold please: What happened to the other columns? And how do I make the other column headings... umm, headings again as dtypes all on the same line as the 'Total' result? Thanks for your help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look the use of `pivot_table`, the columns `['Date','Time','Basket']` are passed as `index` and hence the resulting `DataFrame` as these three variables as `index`.

You can use `reset_index` :

```
pd.concat([Test1.reset_index(), Test2.reset_index()])
```

Comment: Thank you very much Colonel Beauvel! Out of interest, does it matter that the 'Total' colmun headings are on different axis 0 indexes to the other main headings?

Comment: hum maybe I missed something: do you want to concatenante horizontally or vertically? if the triplet ['Date','Time','Basket'] have different values and you concatenante vertically, there is no problem.

Comment: Ah.. I see. My bad. Thanks very much for your help.